# Polylang with move to www

Tags: wordpress, redirect, translation, polylang

I have a 500 error when I switch language. It happened after I changed settings site from http://example.com to http://www.example.com/.

I saved permalinks in Polylang settings and wordpress settings after changes, but nothing happened.